# Probability at least one bingo card has the same numbers if have N total cards in play.

Tags: probability, combinations

A standard bingo card has 5 rows and columns with a free  space in the middle. Each column can be filled from 15 different  numbers since bingo has 75 numbers total; 15 numbers for each column. Thus 4 columns need  5 numbers to be filled   ; thus the number of combinations for each of these columns is 15C5. The middle column requires  only 4 numbers since it has a free space; thus the combinations for this column is 15C4.

I want to know what the probability is that at least one bingo card has the same numbers if N cards are in play. 
I am confused how to calculate this probability . My attempt is as follows:

From above the total number of combinations for a card is 
 [15C5]^4 • [15C4]  - call this product Z.

Thus the probability any 2 cards match is [1/Z] .

Thus the probability the 2 cards do not match is 
[1- (1/Z) ] .

Thus the probability all N cards do not match is 
 [1-(1/Z) ] ^ N .

Finally then the probability P there is at least one card that has all the same numbers is

P  =  1 -  [ 1- (1/Z) ] ^N

I would like to know if my approach is correct; if not what is the correct method .

Answer (score 1):

As you ask the question, what is the probability of another card having the same numbers, it is correct.  That allows a match between a card that has $12345$ in the first column with a card that has $54321$ in the first column.  A card with the numbers in a different order will not allow the same horizontal bingos.  If you want matching cards to include the order of the numbers all your $C$s should be $P$s.

Comment: Ok if I change All the combinations to permutations Is my approach correct ??

Comment: Yes if you agree you want the locations of the numbers to match as well.

Comment: Ok on a bingo web site it states that this probability is approximated by
P  =  1- exp [ - (N/471,000,000) ]. Would appreciate any help where this equation comes from and what is 471,000,000 ?

Comment: I don't know.  I find many more combinations than that.  For large $n$ we have $(1-\frac 1n)^n \approx \exp(-1)$, so $(1-\frac 1n)^{nk} \approx \exp(-k)$.  That expression would be correct if there were only $471,000,000$ combinations.